# accessing special element in xml using linq

Tags: c#, linq

how can I get Password value for specified Username using linq?
For example if Username equals AAAA then passsword is ss.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<User>
    <Username>AAAA</Username>
    <Password>ss</Password> 
</User>
<User> 
    <Username>CCC</Username> 
    <Password>zzz</Password> 
</User>
```

Comment: This is not a valid xml as it does not have a root element

Comment: Please show us your effort to solve this task. Stack Overflow isn't an "how to do this" site. Anyway, SO is plenty of questions like yours. Have a look at the "Related" panel at your right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by saying you should change your xml structure to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<users>
    <User>
        <Username>AAAA</Username>
        <Password>ss</Password> 
    </User>
    <User> 
        <Username>CCC</Username> 
        <Password>zzz</Password> 
    </User>
</users>
```

Then you can try:

```
var username = "AAAA";
var password = XElement.Parse(xml)
    .Elements("User")
    .Where(x=>(string)x.Element("Username") == username)
    .Select(x=>(string)x.Element("Password"));
```

I tend to use `XElement`, but some would say `XDocument` is better:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var username = "AAAA";
var password = xdoc.Root.Elements("User")
    .Where(x=>(string)x.Element("Username") == username)
    .Select(x=>(string)x.Element("Password"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, my structure is just like you edited)

Comment: var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); xml should be the name of xml files? example Users.xml ?

Comment: xml is a string in my example. If you want xml to be a file use `XDocument.Load` instead.

Comment: yes, but password doesn't get the value( when I debugging it stores lot of data

Comment: Try `.FirstOrDefault()` as per my edit. This will get either the first occurrence or a null if it doesn't find a match.